# Grails - severe IllegalStateException - Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: hibernate, exception, tomcat, grails

I'm getting a severe IllegalStateException error on prod environment (stacktrace at the bottom). Locally, on dev everything works fine and I never experienced any problem with that piece of code locally.

Prod and Dev configurations have the same Tomcat 5. On dev I have PostgreSQL 9.2 and on prod 8.4. Pord environment is a VPS on some hosting.

The code that causes it is a simple class instances creator (GameStateTransition class) - it is responslible for initialization and save of over 370 000 instances. The line that causes the error is either save(flush:true) or hibernateSesion.flush()- I tried both options.

The error happens non-deterministically - sometimeas after creating 160 000 instances, sometimes after 220 000, sometimes 300 000...

I thought it may be an issue with memory and the VPS server killing the most memory consuming process, but changing the JAVA_OPTS Xmx to 256m which is way below the 500m limit the server has, did not help. Running the app locally and changing the dev DB to the to the production Postgres 8.4 worked fine (the process finished with no errors) so it must be a problem with the app on prod server.

Anyone has any clue, what it might be about?

What the stacktrace says is something about mongoDB, testing and mocking annotations, but I'm not using any of it. It's a simple code that creates an instances and saves it to the DB.

```
2013-02-08 00:07:50 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-12200"]
2013-02-08 00:07:50 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
2013-02-08 00:07:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
2013-02-08 00:07:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
2013-02-08 00:07:51 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
2013-02-08 00:07:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
2013-02-08 00:07:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
2013-02-08 00:07:52,979 [http-bio-12200-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /gameState/initializeTransitionMatrix
Method on class [pl.edu.caspar.analyzer.GameStateTransition] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.. Stacktrace follows:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [pl.edu.caspar.analyzer.GameStateTransition] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:46)
    at pl.edu.caspar.analyzer.GameStateController$_initializeTransitionMatrix_closure3_closure8.doCall(GameStateController.groovy:59)
    at pl.edu.caspar.analyzer.GameStateController$_initializeTransitionMatrix_closure3.doCall(GameStateController.groovy:53)
    at pl.edu.caspar.analyzer.GameStateController.initializeTransitionMatrix(GameStateController.groovy:52)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the

```
2013-02-08 00:07:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
2013-02-08 00:07:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
```

this looks like the Tomcat process is trying to shut down for some reason, and the exception occurs when you try and execute a controller action in an application that is in the process of shutting down.

You say that

> I thought it may be an issue with memory and the VPS server killing the most memory consuming process, but changing the JAVA_OPTS Xmx to 256m which is way below the 500m limit the server has, did not help

There's more to Java memory than just the heap size (`-Xmx`), there's also the PermGen size (`-XX:MaxPermSize=...`) and other settings for stack space, etc.  You may need to limit those as well in order to keep the process as a whole below the VPS memory limit.

Comment: Yep, that also came to my mind - I set the MaxPermSize to 128m and now the process is running - in 20-30 minutes we should have an answer :) In case that's not good enaugh - what other memory settings would you suggest to look into?

Comment: @Makavelli There's `-Xss` for per-thread stack size but I don't know what the default is for that.  You could maybe also look at tuning the Tomcat thread pool settings in server.xml.

Comment: OK, now I'm 100% sure it's a lack of the memory issue, but no matter how I play with the tuning params, the process always fails. This means that my Grails code is probably wrong - I posted it as another issue on ST (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774799/grils-controller-simple-code-consuming-too-much-memory-how-to-optimise) and will look for some help on that level. Thank you very much for help Ian.